# Perl regex to match pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I need to match a string something like

```
$filecontents = test-app-ref-Man_pub_aut_art_1234;
```

My regex is something like this but it doesn't work: Can someone help me with the regex what I am doing wrong here. Please note that  I am reading the complete file  as a string and this is one of the strings.

```
while($filecontents =~ m/(test)(-|_)(.*)(_\d{4,})$/isgm){
    print " String10 : '$1$2$3$4'\n";
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://www.rubular.com/r/1zOTjOAaWt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you're expecting the string to end with 4 digits, but your string actually ends with 4 digits, then a semi-colon.  add a semi-colon before the `$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, worked for me in Excel

```
(-|_)?.*_\d{4}
```

Result for the given string:

**test-app-ref-Man_pub_aut_art_1234**